# Algorithm behind Sokumenzu / Side View Generator

Tags: algorithm, text, graphics, 3d, rotation

I stumbled across the following novelty website for generating "rotation anagrams" of a given input text called [Sokumenzu / Side View Generator](http://en.genzu.net/sokumen/) which produces animated versions of results such as the following:

[image: Sokumenzu for my name]

I'm really keen to understand the algorithm behind it. I've tried seeing if any of the publicly exposed javascript can help me do so but it is a mess of obfuscation and my grasp of the language isn't so firm that I can't be sure that the real work isn't being done server side.

I have the rough outline of how I think a similar such system could be built but it would have its own short comings (and maybe a small advantage if the real approach is hard-coded):

**Pre-computation**

```
Define an nxnxn cube composed of equally sized sub-cubes
Each sub-cube may either contain a sphere or not
Create a virtual camera orthogonal to one of the cube's faces a fixed distance away
For each of the possible states of the cube:
    Cast rays from the camera and build up an nxn matrix of which cells appear occupied from the camera's point of view.
    Input this matrix into a neural network / other recognizer which has been pre-trained on the latin alphabet.
    If the recognizer matches a character: 
        Add the state which triggered recognition to a hashtable indexed on the character it recognized. 
        Handle collisions (there should be many) by keeping the highest confidence recognition
For every key in the hashtable
    Rotate the corresponding state in fixed increments recognizing characters as before
    If a character other than the current key is recognized:
        Add that character and the amount of rotation performed to a tuple in a list.
    Store each of these lists in the hashtable indexed on the current key.
```

**Query**

```
Generate all of the permutations achieved by substituting each of the characters linked in the list associated with input character at that position.
Find the first dictionary word in the list of permutations
Visualize using the rotation information stored for each character
```

Obviously this isn't the same algorithm as is used since this operates on a character by character basis. I suppose that you could use a similar approach on a word by word basis taking the face of the entire volume as input to a text recognizer but I'm sure that they have probably done something simpler, cleverer, and far far more efficient.

The one advantage of this terrible terrible idea is that by retraining the recognizer you could support other character sets.

Anyone know how this actually works?

Answer (score 4):

I think it is way simpler than that.

For each pair of letters (which are 2d objects), you can try to find a 3d object which will project to one or the other depending if it is seen from a 0° angle or a 90° one.

Finding a set of 3d points on a 3d-grid that project to two given sets of points in 2d depending on the projection looks like a problem of discrete tomography, which you can read about here on Wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_tomography

Note that you can process the 3d shape line by line, and actually only solve 2d instances.

Once that pre-computation is done, and you have a graph of letters where two letters are linked if there is a 3d shape that produces the two of them from a different angle, I suspect the way the algorithm works is as follows :

Compute the set of letters of the original word. Then, explore all the set of letters you can have by changing a letter of the input to one that it is linked to. When you find a set of letters that can make a word, stop. (there is probably a pre-computed dictionary that does a matching between words and sets of letters)

If a 3d shape needs to project in a different part of the word (that is, you need to have a shape that project in position 2 or 4 of the word depending if it is the original word or the other one, like u and v in D(u)ncan - Une(v)en ) you compute the appropriate permutation matrix. Like this for your name :

DU__________

______uv____

__nn________

____ce______

________ae__

__________nn

(first letter of each pair is the letter projected to the left, second letter the one projected to the bottom)

It is computed from the permutation matrix :

100000

000100

010000

001000

000010

000001

And the matching of the letters. (D-U, c-e ...).

Comment: Thank you for both directing me towards discrete tomography and permutation matrices.

Answer (score 1):

The linked demo appears to work with precomputed or maybe even handcrafted letter pairs. A.N. has pointed you on how to rearrange the letter pairs. Note that the Sokumenzu sometimes fails to generate another word, for example with "Lydia". It then maps the word to itself. It also tries an all uppercase version when it doesn't find a match with the given case.

If you want a more general solution, you can combine arbitrary bitmaps of the same height provided that each row that has at least one pixel in the first bitmap also has a pixel in the second bitmap. (So you can't have an `i` on one face and an `l` on the other, because there's will be a pixel in the row between the tittle and the stem of the `i`.)

You can create the layers of your cube independently. Your aim is to have at least one pixel that projects to every pixel of the two bitmaps.

Create a list of the positions of the filled pixels of each bitmap. If one of the lists is empty, there is no solution. Create pairs out of the lists so that all pixels from the longer list are used and each pixel from the shorter list is used at least once.

Depending on the top-down appearence you want to achieve, you can use various algorithms. If you want to create a diagonal, you can use [Bresenham arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm). You can also create a scattered appearance by assigning the pairs randomly, as long as you use every pixel at least once.

To illustrate:

```
                · · · · · · · · · ·
                · · ● · · · · · ○ ○    #
                · · · · · · · · · ·
                · ● · ○ · · ○ · ● ·    #
                · ○ ○ ● · · ● · · ●    #

                  # # #     #   # #
```

Both the discs and the circles will produce the hash patterns, although the circles will look tidier when seen from above and will probably also work better inn perspective.